# Serializing double to an int within POJO

Tags: java, json, serialization, pojo

I am having trouble figuring out how to serialize my a double to an int in my POJO. At the moment, I am sloppily making the conversion within the setter method. The double will always be between 0 and 1. Below are the getter and setter methods within my POJO:

```
@JsonProperty("costMargin")
public int getCostMargin() {
    return costMargin;
}

@JsonProperty("costMargin")
public void setCostMargin(double costMargin) {
        this.costMargin = (int)(Math.round(costMargin * 100));
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to serialize this double to an int, without making the conversion within the setter method? I am trying to look into other ways of doing this, such as creating a serializer class, and including an annotation in my Pojo. for example: @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDoubleSerializer.class)

Comment: What does it mean to "serialize a double to an int"? What happens if the `double` value is too large for an `int`?  You need to clarify what you are trying to accomplish.  From the code it looks like you want to store a financial value as a scaled integer (i.e. cents), in which case what you have works fine as long as you understand how rounding a floating point number may give unexpected results.  You'd be better off not using floating point for financial data anywhere in your code, but you may not have that option.

Comment: Sorry for lack of inclusion of detail. The double will always be between 0 and 1. And I am trying to not to have calculation within my setter or getter methods other than setting and getting.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: you cannot do it.

You have to convert double to int somewhere by truncating or rounding somehow.

In your code you just violate Java Bean specification. Getter returns int, but Setter has double as parameter.

If so, you have to convert in setter. Otherwise you have to do it in the caller before call a setter.

Comment: I am trying to look into other ways of doing this, such as creating a serialize class, and including an annotation in my Pojo: @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDoubleSerializer.class)

Comment: Why not? still you have to convert double to int by your own rules. (i.e. `Math.round` you have) and if you have many fields to do that - custom serializer makes sense. Also to be consistent why do not use super class `java.lang.Number` for getters/setters instead of `int`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDoubleSerializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("costMargin")
         public int getCostMargin() {
         return costMargin;
    }
```

to call

```
public class CustomDoubleSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Double> {

@Override
public void serialize(Double value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    gen.writeObject((int)(Math.round(value * 100)));
}
```

}

public class CustomDoubleSerializer extends JsonSerializer {